# vb.net select first line in textbox

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net I want to select the first line in a textbox.  This is my code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
```

But this selects the entire box, How can I change this so it only gets the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, provided that you add some error handling:

```
Dim arr() As String
arr = New String() {Environment.NewLine}    
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value",TextBox1.Text().Split(arr, StringSplitOptions.None)(0).ToString()
```